# Describing pictures that are part of a brochure

Tags: phrase-request

> He was showing to me **pictures of other members of his orchestra
>   on the invitation brochure** to their concert that would take place on
>   Sunday.

The meaning that is meant to be expressed here is that those pictures of other members are, in fact, a part of the brochure. However, the sentence can also be taken as if those were separate pictures that lay on the brochure.

What would be the best way to avoid that ambiguity?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Thanks for this valuable input. Every time I read your replies, I learn something new.

Comment: Except, more often than not, those "replies" should be answers, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the ambiguity you could express it in one of two different ways.

> He was showing me **additional** pictures of **those** members of his orchestra who **had appeared** in the invitation brochure.

This sentence indicates that the pictures exist separately from the brochure itself.

> He was showing me **all of the** pictures of the members of his orchestra **that appeared inside** the invitation brochure.

In this version, it's made clear that it's the pictures exist only inside the brochure.

---

Note that I changed *on* to *in*, assuming that if you opened up the brochure it would contain more pictures of the people. Idiomatically, *in the brochure* would also be understood to mean *on the front and back covers*. If the pictures only did appear on the front cover (perhaps as some kind of montage), then *on* could be retained—and my second sentence rewritten to accommodate that fact.

Answer (score 2):

Change the preposition to '**in**', unless the pictures are on the cover or the brochure is not a folded type.

Comment: I think you could use "in" even if the pictures were on the cover of the brochure.